# New Activity Goes to Blank Screen

Tags: java, android

I'm pretty new to Android Studio and I'm having difficulty starting a new activity. I've triple checked my code and I can't figure out what my problem is. I've also google searched for a couple of hours but nobody seems to have had the same problem as me. Logcat isn't reporting a problem, but when I run the app, and click the button, the app goes to a blank screen. Please help!

```
public class OriginalFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_original, container, false);

    return rootView;
}

}

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private AlertDialog mDialog;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    //Sets up the about button
    View aboutButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.about_button);
    aboutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setTitle(R.string.about_title);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.about_text);
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok_label,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        }

                    });
            mDialog=builder.show();
        }

    });

    View originalButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.original_button);
    originalButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), OriginalActivity.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    View pictureButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.picture_button);
    originalButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PictureActivity.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if (mDialog != null)
        mDialog.dismiss();
}

}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

}


<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools= "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width= "match_parent"
android:layout_height= "match_parent"
android:clipChildren= "false"
tools:context= "org.example.abstract_art.MainActivity">


<fragment android:id= "@+id/main_fragment"
    class= "org.example.abstract_art.MainFragment"
    android:layout_width= "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity= "center"
    tools:layout= "@layout/fragment_main" />

</FrameLayout>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/select_shapes_background"
tools:context="org.example.abstract_art.OriginalActivity">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select Shapes"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="@dimen/menu_text_size"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<fragment
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="org.example.abstract_art.OriginalFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_original" />


</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/menu_background"
android:elevation="@dimen/elevation_high"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="@dimen/menu_padding"
tools:context=".org.example.abstract_art.MainFragment">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/menu_space"
    android:text="@string/long_app_name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="@dimen/menu_text_size"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/original_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/menu_button_margin"
    android:padding="@dimen/menu_button_padding"
    android:text="@string/original_label"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/picture_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/menu_button_margin"
    android:padding="@dimen/menu_button_padding"
    android:text="@string/picture_label"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/about_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/menu_button_margin"
    android:padding="@dimen/menu_button_padding"
    android:text="@string/about_label"/>


</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/menu_background"

android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="@dimen/menu_padding"
tools:context="org.example.abstract_art.OriginalFragment">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Circles"
    android:id="@+id/circlesText"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/menu_text_size"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Rectangles"
    android:id="@+id/rectanglesText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/circlesText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/menu_text_size"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Squares"
    android:id="@+id/squaresText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rectanglesText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/menu_text_size"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Triangles"
    android:id="@+id/trianglesText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/squaresText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/menu_text_size"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="4 Point Stars"
    android:id="@+id/fourStarText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/trianglesText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/menu_text_size"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="6 Point Stars"
    android:id="@+id/sixStarText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fourStarText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/menu_text_size"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Create Art!"
    android:id="@+id/createOriginalButton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/sixStarText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Show your logcat or something helps reproduce the error ?

Comment: Did you define your new activity in you Manifest?

Comment: Does your layout have any content?

Comment: post  your xml and manifest code please.

Comment: Where u load fragment? in xml? Use fragment activity if u use fragment in xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please Make sure Below Things**

1. You have Define Main Activity, OriginalActivity,PictureActivity in your Manifest file
2. Please Make sure You also set Layout in all Activity or Fragment and Bind Components Of All Layout in that class
3. try below code

   Button originalBtn; //Define class Level

   ```
   originalBtn=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.original_button);
   ```

**Now you can set click Listener and code in it**

**Second main things that you define two times originalButton Click Listener so i think thats why you get problem**

**I think second Listener should be pictureButton Click Listener**

Comment: You were right! The problem was I meant to write pictureButton not originalButton. Thanks!

Comment: @WilliamWill thats why it conflict and create problem. give up vote if it work well